# How to create user and group in AD using Lambda

Tags: python, linux, lambda, active-directory, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a function using Lambda in Python on Linux. I have tried to use `pyad`, but it gave me *`Exception: Must be running Windows in order to use pyad.`*

What other way can i create user and group in AD?

Thanks

Comment: You should show the relevant code, and explain a little more on how its being used. For example, are you trying to do it on a local machine through a Bash prompt, or are you trying to do it remotely over the network? Is the machine running the software joined to a domain? Is the host Windows, or is it Linux with Samba?

Comment: @jww the end goal for me to is to use the AWS lambda serverless python, it will connect to the AD remotely over the network and add user, but to test it, i have been running the python script on a linux server. just simply `import pyad` would give me that error. The machine is joined on the domain, and the AD is hosted on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 aspects that you should pay attention.

1. Lambda runs in a Linux environment. So, if you have some library that uses internal resources from windows, it won't work on AWS Lambda environment. You should search another option, like python-ldap or something similar.
2. Lambda environment provides only basic python modules. For sure pyad or python-ldap is not included. So, if you want to use it, make sure you will add this module in your zip lambda file.

Comment: ya, now i am now testing on ldap3 to see if it work. I have created a virtual environment for python, will use it to create a Lambda package. hope it works

Comment: Any sucess on ldap3. Not able to connect DC